# Como filtrar apenas o último dia de cada mês?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, script

Como posso filtrar uma *query* trazendo o resultado pelo último dia de cada mês, no SQL Server 2012? Tentei o *EOMONTH*, porém acusa erro, creio que devido à versão.

```
SELECT E8_FILIAL,
       E8_AGENCIA, E8_CONTA, 
       E8_DTSALAT, 
       E8_SALATUA 
  FROM SE8010 AS SE8
 WHERE E8_CONTA IN ('84361','22700') 
   AND D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
   AND YEAR(E8_DTSALAT) = 2018
```

Preciso trazer estes campos filtrando pelo dia 31/01, 28(ou 29)/02, 31/03, 30/04, etc.

o campo data é o *E8_DTSALAT*

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: @MarcianoMachado Sql Server

Comment: Se entendi bem a tua duvida, tu quer filtrar do dia 31 até o dia 1, é isso? Neste caso poderia usar um `order by E8_DTSALAT desc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do SQL 2012 deveria poder usar o `EOMONTH`:

```
SELECT  E8_FILIAL
    ,   E8_AGENCIA
    ,   E8_CONTA
    ,   E8_DTSALAT
    ,   E8_SALATUA 
FROM    SE8010 AS SE8
WHERE   E8_CONTA                    IN ('84361','22700') 
    AND D_E_L_E_T_                  <> '*' 
    AND YEAR(E8_DTSALAT)            = 2018 
    AND CAST(E8_DTSALAT AS DATE)    = EOMONTH(E8_DTSALAT)
```

Mas caso a versão não o permita pode fazer de outra forma:

```
SELECT  E8_FILIAL
    ,   E8_AGENCIA
    ,   E8_CONTA
    ,   E8_DTSALAT
    ,   E8_SALATUA 
FROM    SE8010 AS SE8
WHERE   E8_CONTA                    IN ('84361','22700') 
    AND D_E_L_E_T_                  <> '*' 
    AND YEAR(E8_DTSALAT)            = 2018 
    AND CAST(E8_DTSALAT AS DATE)    = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, E8_DTSALAT) + 1, 0) - 1 AS DATE)
```

---

```
CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, E8_DTSALAT) + 1, 0) - 1 AS DATE)
```

O `DATEADD` permite adicionar um valor, seja dia, mês, ano, hora, etc, a uma determinada data;

O atributo `MONTH` refere que queremos adicionar meses à data;

O `DATEDIFF` devolve a diferença entre duas datas, onde neste caso devolve o total de meses entre a data mínima e a data que se encontra na coluna `E8_DTSALAT`;

Por fim o `CAST` permite converter o valor para uma data apenas (sem hora, minuto, segundo, etc).

O que este código faz é basicamente retirar 1 dia ao primeiro do mês seguinte ao contido em `E8_DTSALAT`, obtendo assim o último dia do mês.

Comment: estava preparando a resposta mas não deu tempo =p é isso mesmo!! (estranho é que o `EOMONTH` está [disponível a partir do _2012_](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Comment: @João Martins funcionou, poderia explicar o último AND na condição Where, da opção sem o eomonth,por favor? Meus conhecimentos não vão muito além do básico.

Comment: Certo, também vi a mesma coisa! Algo que pode estar a acontecer é a instância SQL ser uma versão anterior à 2012 mas o SSMS ser a versão 2012!

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro resposta editada para conter mais informação. Não se esqueça de dar um UP e/ou aceitar a resposta se lhe foi útil!

Answer (score 0):

> *Preciso trazer estes campos filtrando pelo dia 31/01, 28(ou 29)/02, 31/03, 30/04, etc.*
>   *O campo data é o E8_DTSALAT*

Pelo que entendi, deseja que a consulta retorne as informações nos dias 31/1/2018, 28/2/2018, ..., 31/12/2018. A princípio cada mês possui sempre o mesmo número de dias, exceto nos anos bissextos, para o mês de fevereiro.

Eis uma sugestão, em que se informa o ano; a partir dele o último dia de cada mês desse ano é gerado através de CTE (*common table expression*).

```
-- código #1
-- informe o ano
declare @Ano smallint;
set @Ano= 2018;

--
with 
Inicio_Meses as (
SELECT convert (date, ('1/'+cast(n as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(@Ano as char(4))), 103) as Data_Inicio
 from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) as Mes (n)
),
Fim_Meses as (
SELECT dateadd (day, -1, dateadd (month, +1, Data_Inicio)) as Data_Fim
  from Inicio_Meses
)
-- a consulta
SELECT E8_FILIAL, E8_AGENCIA, E8_CONTA, 
       E8_DTSALAT, E8_SALATUA 
  from SE8010 AS SE8
 where SE8.E8_CONTA in ('84361','22700') 
       and SE8.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
       and SE8.E8_DTSALAT in (SELECT Data_Fim from Fim_Meses);
```

---

A CTE Fim_Meses gera o último dia de cada mês, de acordo com o ano informado. Para fins de testes, experimente:

```
-- código #2 v2
declare @Ano smallint;
set @Ano= 2020;

with 
Inicio_Meses as (
SELECT convert (date, ('1/'+cast(n as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(@Ano as char(4))), 103) as Data_Inicio
 from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) as Mes (n)
),
Fim_Meses as (
SELECT Data_Inicio, 
       dateadd (day, -1, dateadd (month, +1, Data_Inicio)) as Data_Fim
  from Inicio_Meses
)
SELECT * from Fim_Meses;
```